# Check if paragraph font style is italic or not?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to find if a paragraph is italics or not, i am iterating to all paragraph through a for loop, if the paragraph is italics i want to do some operation.

```
For Each oPara In .Paragraphs
    With oPara
      If oParaAttrItalic = True Then
          .Style = "new_style"
      End If
    End With
Next
```

Comment: what is 'oParaAttrItalic'? If I might ask.

Comment: i just tried using oParaAttrItalic

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Paragraph.Range reference

```
Dim oPara As Paragraph

For Each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If oPara.Range.Font.Italic = True Then
        'Do something
    End If
Next oPara
```

Comment: Its not detecting the paragraph which have fully italics text

Comment: so the condition is never true?? or does it work for some paragraphs with italic text and not for others

Comment: Looks as though there are multiple states. If you want to check if ANY text in the paragraph is italic you can test for oPara.Range.Font.Italic <> False

Comment: I want to check if the whole paragraph is in italics not just a part of the paragraph @Dave please help.

Comment: You may need to share an example document because as far as I can tell, this should work. If your entire paragraph is in italics, the Paragraph.Range.Italic property returns -1 (True), if part of the paragraph is italic, it returns 9999999 (for our purpose here you can consider this Not False), if none of your paragraph is italic, it should return 0 (False). What value is being returned when you encounter a paragraph you expect to return True?